# CDI: get reference to beanManager via static method

Tags: java, cdi, jboss-weld, pax

I use weld+paxcdi on java se. I can get the reference to beanManager using

```
@Inject
BeanManager beanManager;
```

However, it's clear that I can use this way only in objects that are managed by CDI container. How can I get reference to beanmanager in object that was created by new?

Comment: Does CDI.current().getBeanManager() not work? Cf. https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/beanmanager_obtain_contextual_reference_to

Comment: @Hein Blöd It throws Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access CDI at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.current(CDI.java:65)

Comment: I overlooked that you're on Java SE; did you follow the instructions in the [reference manual](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_java_se) then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the question refers to OSGi, as it wouldn't make sense to use Pax CDI otherwise.

Pax CDI creates a separate CDI container and thus a separate bean manager per bean bundle. For this reason, it is not quite obvious what the *current* bean manager should be.

As of Pax CDI 1.0.0.RC1, `CDI.current()` returns a meaningful value when called from an `OsgiServiceProvider` method, if the method target is an injection point in the calling class. `CDI.current()` is undefined otherwise.

Pax CDI 0.x is based on CDI 1.0 and thus does not support `CDI.current()`.

Comment: You are right - this is osgi+cdi. Could you explain in details what to do in order to use CDI.current()?

Comment: Please, take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871453/pax-cdi-how-to-get-reference-to-beanmanager-in-bundle-without-using-cdi