# PAX-CDI: how to get reference to BeanManager in bundle without using CDI

Tags: java, osgi, cdi, weld

There is a bundle A and threre is a class MyClass in bundle A. And we suppose that pax-cdi+weld is on.

Can can I get reference to BeanManager of the bundle A inside MyClass without using @Inject and other CDI annotations? Via osgi service? Or how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up the `CdiContainer` OSGi service and invoke `getBeanManager()`.

With recent versions of Pax CDI `CDI.current().getBeanManager()` should work as well.

Having said that, the whole idea of Pax CDI is to make CDI work in OSGi just like in Java EE. Accessing the `BeanManager` is a bit of a design smell, unless you are developing a CDI extension.